# How to ensure DC input stays positive regardless of a positive or negative voltage input?

Tags: voltage, dc

What is the "most" correct way to deal with a DC source that can have a +/-input voltage? For example I have a hand crank generator. Spinning the handle one way generates 0 to +20 volts, spinning the other way creates 0 to -20. I need to insure its always positive regardless of hand crank direction. My first thought was a configuration of either diodes or transistors. I assume there is a standard way but i'm not sure what term to google.

Comment: Diodes would be your starting point.  Depending on the circumstances you can either block or short reverse voltages.

Comment: Bridge Rectifier.

Comment: Would it be the same configuration as a bridge rectifier? I can't seem to find any examples but I'm not 100% what you would call this type of circuit?

Comment: Read the above - "Bridge Rectifier."

Comment: Ok so yes, you just use a bridge Rectifier circuit? It was the first thing I searched but I only saw examples for ac to dc, not for dc to dc.

Comment: DC is only a special case of AC in this case, but your fears of assuming they are identical in general are sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The **bridge rectifier** is the cheapest and simplest one.

Only two diodes will be conducting for the whole duration.
[image]

A few things to consider:

1. If the required DC voltage is very close to the input DC voltage, schottky diodes can be considered because if their lower *forward voltage drop*.  Schottky diodes are bulkier and costlier than normal diodes.
2. If reverse leakage current is a concern. Normal diode can be used only at the cost of a little higher voltage drop.
3. The voltage drop will be two times the forward voltage drop of single diode.
4. If no voltage drop can be tolerated PMOSFET can also be used which drops only a few 10s of mV when properly chosen. The drop will be the load current times the on resistance of FET times 2.

Comment: Thank you, it was the first thing that came to mind but when I googled I found no examples so I did not even bother to try it on a bread board. Worked just as I needed it too!